# Recommendations for accessible thermodynamics textbooks?

Tags: thermodynamics

I've recently started a new job where my very, *very* limited thermodynamics background (intro + intermediate, 10+ yrs ago in undergrad) is starting to be an issue. I am looking for recommendations for thermo textbooks or other relatively-intro-level resources that are, most of all, *accessible* - somewhat conversational; not all derivations, but rigorous enough to be used as a reference; tying the content back to real physical problems, etc. The best example I can give of a texbook that meets these criteria is Peter Corke's *Robotics, Vision and Control* - a very different field, but a book that I have literally had on my nightstand and read before bed. Any suggestions for textbooks/reference books like this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: this is a question and answer site ... if someone  suggests a very good book and someone else suggests another equally good book, then how will you choose  which one is the correct one?

Comment: eh... while it is ofc against the SE rules to recommend references, I think it's mostly to avoid starting bitter arguments. Imagine the CS people arguing about whether Donald Knuth was worth reading. Not enough traffic in this backwater for such a thing, I don't think.... Plus I'm curious about this one myself.

Comment: I recently downloaded Jeremy Tatum's free book on Thermo from LibreTexts. https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Thermodynamics_and_Statistical_Mechanics/Heat_and_Thermodynamics_(Tatum)   ... Too soon to recommend. Though he does throw in a few dad-jokes. I will say, the subject is inherently full of math, and his treatment of it doesn't spare the reader. I do think it was better than the text I had in engineering school.

Comment: who would call 2 thermo classes very very limited background?  You take Thermo I & II as an ME.

Comment: Mechanics of Fluids by Massey - available new, or secondhand bookshops or for the really cheap option as a pdf tht you can download / access : https://archive.org/details/mechanicsoffluid0000mass_h7n0

Comment: Thanks, yall! Really appreciate the two recs - will check them out. 


“Limited background” - I dunno about you, but for me it doesn’t matter how many classes I took - I don’t really understand technical material until I’ve had to solve a real-world problem with it. Intervening decade of focus on robotics and control isn’t helping

Comment: If you had focus in robotics and control, I suspect you are familiar with Ohms law and circuits.  You can convert all thermo problems into an equivalent circuit problem.  Given all the fancy electronics these days, it can be harder to go the other way.